# Show if $Q ∩[0,1]$ is compact?

Tags: analysis, compactness

> Show if $Q ∩[0,1]$ is compact.

It is bounded. It contains it limit point $1$, therefore it is closed = > compact.

What is wrong with this conclusion?

Comment: Is $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ a limit point? Does it belong to the set?

Comment: Is $\mathbb Q$ the rationals?

Comment: What's wrong with your conclusion is that you haven't show that it contains *all* it's limit points. You've just shown it for $1$. $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is certainly bounded, but it's by no means closed. As many here have pointed out, $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \cap [0,1]$ are all boundary points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is *not* compact. Take *any* irrational point $p$ in $(0,1)$. Then $p\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)}$, but $p\notin\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$ is not a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ and so it cannot be compact.

Comment: So, to be compact every point in the sequence must be a limit point?

Comment: @SargisIskandaryan Which sequence? There is no sequence in your question.

Comment: I mean by definition. I saw one but didn’t understand it really

Comment: @SargisIskandaryan A bounded subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ is compact if and only if when a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $a\in\mathbb R$, then $a\in A$.

Answer (score 4):

For each $\alpha\in\mathbb Q\cap (0,1)$, let $$I_\alpha=\begin{cases}[0,\alpha)&\alpha^2<\frac{1}{2}\\(\alpha,1]&\alpha^2>\frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$

Show that the $I_\alpha$ are open in $X=\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$, and that they cover $X,$ but there is no finite sub-cover.

Answer (score 0):

The set is not compact in $\Bbb R$. Take the following subsequence $$a_n=\text{the first n digits in the decimal representation of } \pi -3\text{ after decimal point}$$for example$$a_1=0.1\\a_2=0.14\\a_3=0.151\\.\\.\\.$$then any subsequence of $a_n$ tends to $\pi -3\notin Q\cap[0,1]$.